# Can I use "should" to mean "if"? "but he has outlined other priorities should he be elected mayor in November."

Tags: word-usage

In the following sentence, does *should* mean *if*?

> Eric Adams made reducing crime the main theme of his primary campaign, but he has outlined other priorities **should** he be elected mayor in November.

Comment: Yes, "if he is elected" and "should he be elected" carry the same meaning, although they have differing grammatical structures.

Comment: Note that the sentence makes sense only if we stretch the grammar or understand it elliptically. "he has outlined other priorities [that he will address] should he be elected" or "he has outlined other [items that will take priority] should he be elected."

Answer (score 1):

It's an inverted conditional.  With this kind of inversion, the word "if" is dropped.

While "should" may at first glance seem to function like "if", actually the word "should" can be included in the non-inverted form (although this not common).  You can say any of the following:

- **if he is elected** mayor in November
- **if he should be elected** mayor in November
- **should he be elected** mayor in November

Both versions with "should" are more formal (and perhaps more tentative) than the plain "if he is" version.

Past perfects (representing unreal conditions) can also be inverted this way, so the following two phrases are equivalent to each other:

- **if he had been elected**
- **had he been elected**

Likewise, the following two phrases are equivalent to each other:

- **if he were elected**
- **were he elected**

Comment: "if he should be elected mayor in November" the word "should" in this setence seems to be breaking the logic of this setence, Don't you think so? if you read it literally @rjpond

Comment: If by "literally" you mean interpreting "should" as a modal of obligation, I agree, it wouldn't make sense. But "should" has other meanings (although they may be less common). One of those is its formal use to refer to a possible situation or contingency ( see lexico.com/definition/should sense 3).

Comment: @user139517 It seems to me the problem you are having with the sentence at issue arises from the fact that you are simply not familiar with this usage of "should". You are better off just memorizing it as such and the examples rjpond gives in their answer.